Изменение типа, если не null
Описание
Очень часто случается, что нужно из переменной типа T достать какое-то свойство типа U.
Иногда случается такое с переменной типа T | null. В таком случае, если значение null мы возвращаем null, в противном случае достаем переменную типа U. То есть результат может быть U | null.
Реализация
Теперь эту же логику пытаюсь реализовать как функцию. Примерно так правда?
function map<T, U>(value: T, callback: (object: NonNullable<T>) => NonNullable<U>): U

... ну как бы чтобы использовать вот так:
type Nullable<T> = T | null;

let text: Nullable<string> = `Hello world`;
const size: Nullable<number> = map<Nullable<string>, Nullable<number>>(text, nonNullableText => nonNullableText.length);


В таком случае делаю простейшую реализацию:
function map<T, U>(value: T, callback: (object: NonNullable<T>) => NonNullable<U>): U {
    if (value === null || value === undefined) return value; // null | undefined
    else return callback(value); // NonNullable<U>
} // NonNullable<U> | null | undefined тот же самый U

Получаю ошибку Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'U'. в части return value.
Вопрос
Нуу, по идеи ошибка логичная, но в какой части логики я ошибся?
Как...
function map<T, U>(value: T, callback: (object: NonNullable<T>) => NonNullable<U>): U

...правильно реализовать?

Дополнительно
Заголовок можете изменить. Не смог правильно описать ошибку.

«эту же логику пытаюсь реализовать как функцию» — а зачем? const size: number | undefined = text?.length

Из-за некоторых причин желаю не использовать undefined. Просто примем что нам не надо его использовать. Нужно получить number | null

const size: number | null = text?.length ?? null;

А во теме вопроса логично что ругается, ведь нет никаких гарантий, что вызывающий расставит все эти Nullable в типах T и U, плюс вы ещё почему-то пытаетесь вернуть undefined, хотя ваш же тип Nullable это явно запрещает

@andreymal в примере я показал маленький участок кода, как text.length. На самом деле там моет быть довольно большая конструкция типа этой. В таких случаях значение с исключением null гораздо легче использовать.

Явно переносим все эти гарантии в объявление функции map, фиксим return, фиксим место вызова функции — и больше не ругается: function map<T, U>(value: Nullable<T>, callback: (object: T) => U): Nullable<U>

@andreymal я пытался использовать "системный" тип NonNullable<T> который так же исключает undefined. Поэтому и пришлось с undefined тоже возиться.

ведь нет никаких гарантий, что вызывающий расставит все эти Nullable в типах T и U - Ну и пусть. Не думаю что это проблема.

Если бы это не было проблемой, вы бы не задали этот вопрос ¯\(ツ)/¯

@andreymal нуу... :) Скорее хотел сказать, что это тоже логичный вариант. Просто теряется смылс использования этой функции.

А компилятору пофиг на смыслы, ему нужно доказать, что ошибочную ситуацию в принципе невозможно получить. Ваше объявление из функции map это не доказывает, моё из коммента выше — доказывает

@andreymal можете, пожалуйста, показывать вызов моего объявления где ситуация ошибочная?

Если U не Nullable, а value === null, то функция map попытается вернуть null, а это невозможно, потому что возвращаемый тип U не Nullable (ну и про undefined аналогично). В моём объявлении возвращаемый тип явно указан как Nullable и такой проблемы нет

@andreymal понял вас, спасибо. Можете оставить как ответ, чтобы я принял.

Функция с типами:
function example<
  T,
  CB extends (obj: NonNullable<T>) => unknown,
  R = T extends NonNullable<T> ? ReturnType<CB> : null
>(input: T, cb: CB): R {
  return (
    input === null || input === undefined
      ? null
      : cb(input)
  ) as R;
}

const q1 = example(null, () => {});
const q2 = example('hello world', (str) => str.replace(/\s/g, '').length);
const q3 = example({ a: null, b: null }, (obj) => Object.keys(obj).join('/'));

Типы переменных в которых хранится результат выполнения:
const q1: null
const q2: number
const q3: string

[LOG]: null 
[LOG]: 10 
[LOG]: "a/b"

